# Creating a SOAP wrapper to an existing REST web service

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a Web API service (REST). I need to add a SOAP endpoint so I can use it in BizTalk. Can anyone tell me the best way to implement a SOAP endpoint to be consumed by BizTalk?

Answer (score 0):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Instead, *adapt* it.

1. Create a client for your existing REST service. You may already have client code that you use to test your REST service.
2. Create a *new* WCF service, with all of the service operations you want exposed from your REST service. This will not be a one-to-one match with your REST service. For instance, you may have `GET /Users`, which will become a `GetAllUsers()` operation, and `GET /User/{id}` which will become `GetUserById(id)`.
3. Have the service operations of your new SOAP service call your client code.

Comment: I have two web services I would need to do this to. One service calls the other. Creating two additional WCF services just to support SOAP seems very inefficient to me.